# Sorting vector of QPointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, qpointer

I have:

```
std::vector< QPointer<ToDoItem> > items;
```

and the call to sort:

```
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), custComparFunction)
```

I am using the custom sorting function:

```
bool ToDoList::custComparFunc(QPointer<ToDoItem> i1, QPointer<ToDoItem> i2){
    if (i1.data()->getSecsTillDeadline() == i2.data()->getSecsTillDeadline()){
        return i1.data()->getMainText() < i2.data()->getMainText();
    }
    return i1.data()->getSecsTillDeadline() < i2.data()->getSecsTillDeadline();
}
```

I am trying to sort a vector of QPointers based on the value returned by 'getSecsTillDeadline()' function

but I am getting the error 'must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer to member function'.

where am I going wrong? the error is in a file predefined_ops.h so I would imagine that there is something in my own code I can change to make this work

the full error is:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:121: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (ToDoList::*)(QPointer<ToDoItem>, QPointer<ToDoItem>)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (ToDoList::*)(QPointer<ToDoItem>, QPointer<ToDoItem>)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (ToDoList::*)(QPointer<ToDoItem>, QPointer<ToDoItem>)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<bool (ToDoList::*)(QPointer<ToDoItem>, QPointer<ToDoItem>)>::_M_comp) (...)'
     { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
                                          ^
```

Comment: `Qpointer` has an overloaded `operator ->` - you don't need the `.data()` part.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Is that all the compiler is saying, there's nothing else? And `item` or `ToDoItem`?

Comment: Is `getSecsTillDeadline` or `getMainText` a pointer to a member function?

Comment: both of those functions are simple member functions in the ToDoItem class

Comment: What line does the error happen on?  What is the exact error text?

Comment: Post the entire error message, the definition of `ToDoItem`, and an indication of where in this function this error occurs.

Comment: Where do you call `std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), custComparFunction)` at in your code?  Is it in a `ToDoList` member function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems form the error message that `custComparFunction` is a non-static member function in the `ToDoItem` class. You can't use non-static member functions like "normal" non-member function pointers.

The simplest solution is to make the function a `static` member function.